# how to change a property of an input tag in C#

Tags: c#, html, tags, webbrowser-control

I'm usig C# web browser control.
The input tag is as follows:

```
input id="txtText" class=" ImageAttached" type="text" style="width:100px;" name="txtText"  image_attached="true"
```

How can I change the image_attached to false.

I'm using the following code but the image is still attached.

```
  elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txtText");
        if (elements != null)
             {                     
                 elements.SetAttribute("image_attached", "false");
              }
```

Comment: This is pretty vague.

Comment: You said "The input tag is as follows:", where is the rest of the sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the debugger to set a breakpoint on the assignment, step over it and see if your SetAttribute method is even being called. If that statement never gets reached, then there is a problem with your assignment above.